# First Android application open wizard

Tags: android

I was looking to a solution which let me to insert a wizard in an Android Application,
when it is opened for the first time. I have a simple Model, which contains 3 strings and I want the user to insert those values, in 3 separate views and at end a summary. What kind of solution do you suggest me ? The data will be store in the shared preferences

Comment: Use shared preferences to store a boolean that determines if the wizard has been shown or not. Initially it is false and if it is false - show the wizard and set the boolean to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would say create a fragment that contains all the views and insert that into your app and add in a boolean variable that is set "true" after they complete the wizard. Add in an if stayement that checks the value of the boolean, so when the value is false it will run the wizard and if it is true then it continues on to the app. There is probably a better way but its the best I could come up with at midnight

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So for create the wizard I need to create a fregment of the MainActivity which well create it depends on the boolean status of the variable, which will be stored in the shared preference settings, isn't ?